# What are the statistical fallacies of illusion of control?

Tags: bias, games, selection-bias, fallacy

[Illusion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_control)<sup>*</sup> appears in gambling and events involving randomness. For example, choosing a lottery ticket which has an additional information that participant has a control of choosing, such as photos of some actors of their preference appearing on the ticket, even though underlying ticket numbers are random process. What are the statistical fallacies falls into Illusion of control? The [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) may be one of them.

<sup>*</sup> A recent popular book [Jackpot](https://guardianbookshop.com/jackpot-9781783352241) discusses this.

Edit:
Assigning a value to $P(A|B)$ whereby, in fact $A$ is independent of $B$.

Edit:
A relevant recent work of Yale researchers: [Does Having a Choice Provide an Illusion of Control?](https://insights.som.yale.edu/insights/does-having-choice-provide-an-illusion-of-control)

Comment: The illusion of control doesn't seem to me to involve a statistical fallacy, *per se*. More a matter of magical thinking, maybe, but in any case perhaps it belongs on psychology.

Comment: @Glen_b It seems like in the illusion of control, there is some fallacy on the interpretation of conditional probabilities.

Comment: $P\left(\text{Win Lottery}\right) < P\left(\text{Win Lottery}\mid \text{Pick Numbers}\right)$ assumed when $P\left(\text{Win Lottery}\right) = P\left(\text{Win Lottery}\mid \text{Pick Numbers}\right)$ is correct?

Comment: @Dave  Yes, inequalities you proposed have similar effect I think . Instead of "Pick Numbers", people pick for example tickets  with "photos of some actors of their preference appearing on the ticket".